# Problem with Jasig CAS webflow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, cas

I have CAS 3.4.3 in my pom. From Jasig CAS zip I included all configuration including login-webflow.xml

The same configuration was working for me when I built my application with CAS source. Currently I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 33): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'neq'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:118)
```

Has anyone encountered this kind of error? It happens when InternalSpelExpressionParser is evaluating flowScope.ticketGrantingTicketId neq null

is this sample login-webflow.xml even correct? I have looked through several references and haven't found anything on expression 'neq'...

My login-webflow.xml is exactly the same as found [here](https://developer.jasig.org/source/browse/jasigsvn/cas3/tags/cas-server-3.4.3/cas-server-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/login-webflow.xml?r=HEAD)

Answer (score 0):

Oh its sad to be stupid. Spent a lot of time thinking it was a dependency issue but actually cas 3.4.3 has different cas-servlet.xml that contains following:

```
<bean id="expressionParser" class="org.springframework.webflow.expression.WebFlowOgnlExpressionParser" />
```